# Why is autocomplete filling in a promo code field with people's addresses when they use Safari?

Tags: html, autocomplete, safari

I have a field in a form of mine for promotional codes, this is the source

```
<input class="form-control helen-checkout-promo-input" type="text" placeholder="Apply a promo code" name="promo" autocomplete="new-promo">
```

Somehow, and I can't seem to recreate this, people keep entering their address into this field. The only thing I can think that would be causing this would be auto complete. Based on the user agents that I'm seeing this, it comes from mostly iPhones, and sometimes Safari on MacOS, this is one of them

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_4 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148
>   Safari/604.1

I've tried setting this to "off", "new", "new-promo", removing the attribute all together, yet I still see this happening many times a day. How do I tell Safari to stop auto-filling this field?

(I know this isn't an accident, because it's been happening maybe 10 times a day over the course of a few months, but fixing it eludes me)

Comment: From what I have experienced as a user on chrome is that usual field (name, email, phone) hints the user to auto complete the whole form with info (phone, address) already stored in browser. A lot of this is driven by the names of field. renaming your fields to not so common names (name, email, promo etc.) may fix this issue.

Comment: Renaming to uncommon names? I can't imagine "promo" is a common field for things to put an address into, especially since this seems to be isolated to Safari

Comment: Just something extra, in UX design it is considered bad practice to put the description/name of the input field as a placeholder *inside* the input field.  This is because if the user accidentally inputs the wrong information into an input, they can no longer see what the input was actually *for* without erasing the text.  I would suggest you don't use a placeholder attribute, but rather place description text directly above the input box.

Comment: @BrianLeishman does my answer help?

Comment: @Jodast sorry! It took me a day to get back around to this with all the work projects I'm on, but it's implemented, I'll wait a over the weekend to make sure none of these show in the log again and then we'll see if it worked on Monday :)

Comment: Sounds good!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the input to `readonly`, then the autocomplete will not input anything into the field because *nothing* can be inputted into the field.  You can put another attribute in the tag that will disable `readonly` on focus, so when the user selects the field to type in their input, readonly will be disabled.  This way, autocomplete can't try to fill in this field and the address won't be inputted into the promo code box (unless, of course, autocomplete isn't the problem, and the problem is just a bunch of apple enthusiasts trying to troll you).

Code: `<input class="form-control helen-checkout-promo-input" type="text" placeholder="Apply a promo code" name="promo" autocomplete="new-promo" readonly="" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');">`

Happy coding!

Comment: Looks like it worked! Zero of those errors over the weekend, Friday afternoon, and this morning. Hacky as hell but gotta love it

Comment: An update a month later, this continues to have removed every instance of people entering their address into my promo code field

Comment: great!  I'm glad this fixed your problem